# How to compare item of two array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I created a system that can save within an array of values taken from a website, these values are updated in real time. Now I'm implementing an additional mode able to see what value is changed. First of all values except downloaded something like "vecchia_lista", then I would make sure to compare every single element of the array and see if the old data differ from new.

```
Dim lista As New List(Of Country_Data)
Dim vecchia_lista As New List(Of Country_Data)
Private Structure Country_Data
    Dim casa As String
    Dim ospite As String
    Dim Result As String
End Structure
```

in the function of updating values I've a nested loop like this content:

```
Dim squadra As Country_Data
                    With squadra
                        .casa = Remove_Tags(Team_A(Team).Groups(1).Value)
                        .ospite = Remove_Tags(Team_B(Team).Groups(1).Value)
                        .Result = StrScore
                    End With
                    lista.Add(squadra)
```

the variable **Team A,b,StrScore** contain split element.
Before this loop I update the old array with new content:

```
vecchia_lista = lista
```

**My problem:**

Now I want to check if a certain element in the array is changed or not, I honestly have no idea how to compare every single instance. I created for to iterate each element of the list, I ask your help to do this.

```
For Each element In lista

                    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's quite hard do understand your question, but it seems you're looking to find elements with the same key in two different collections that differ in a specific property, where the key is `{Casa, Ospite}` and the other property `Result`.

I suggest using [`Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534675(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to match elements in collection A to their counterparts in collection B and check if the value their `Result` property are unequal.

Example:

```
Public Class Country_Data
    Public Property Casa As String
    Public Property Ospite As String
    Public Property Result As String
End Class

Sub Main
    Dim vecchia_lista = New List(Of Country_Data) From _
        { New Country_Data() With {.Casa = "Team A", .Ospite = "Team B", .Result = "0:0"},
          New Country_Data() With {.Casa = "Team C", .Ospite = "Team D", .Result = "0:0"}}

    Dim lista = New List(Of Country_Data) From _
        { New Country_Data() With {.Casa = "Team A", .Ospite = "Team B", .Result = "0:0"},
          New Country_Data() With {.Casa = "Team C", .Ospite = "Team D", .Result = "1:0"}}

    Dim changed_elements = From d1 In vecchia_lista
                           Join d2 in lista On d1.Casa Equals d2.Casa And 
                                               d1.Ospite Equals d2.Ospite
                           Where d1.Result <> d2.Result
                           Select New With {.Casa = d1.Casa, .Ospite = d1.Ospite,
                                            .OldResult = d1.Result, .NewResult = d2.Result}
End Sub
```

`changed_elements` now contains:

[image]

Comment: @Debug Sure. Why not?

Comment: then I would put immediately after the condition <>?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes; `changed_elements` will query all changed items so you can simply iterate over it or whatever you want.

Comment: Where d1.Result <> d2.Result
                           messagebox.show; the compiler show me error

Comment: Maybe it was not clear. Use something like like `For Each element in changed_elements MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", element.Casa, element.Ospite, element.OldResult, element.NewResult)) Next` instead of chaning the query.